# Venn representation of $(P \cup Q) \cap R$. What did I do wrong?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's say you have a question of sets saying:

$$(P \cup Q) \cap R$$

I answer this way:

[image]

(The black part is the shaded)

But the correct answer looks like this:

[image]

(The black part is the shaded)

So why is it like this? Aren't you supposed to shade everything if the question wants union?

Comment: why are you ignoring the intercept R ?

Comment: No? I didn't? I shaded R too?

Comment: Why did you shade it *too*, when you should have shaded the intersection *only*?  You wanted (P or Q) *and* R.

Comment: P union Q, that's why

Comment: Then intersect R

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to shade everything within the $P$ and $Q$ regions to get their union. But, after that, you only want the part of that union which also belongs to $R$.

Comment: OMG thank you! Now I get it!

Answer (score 1):

The question is $$(P \cup Q) \cap R$$

the region must intersect with $R$. You have shaded region that are outside $R$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(P\cup Q)\cap R$ and $P\cup(U\cap R)$ are different things, and just from $P\cup Q\cap R$ we won't know which one we're asked about. The given answer represents the former. Your answer represents just $P\cup Q$, however, and that is incorrect regardless of which of the two above interpretations is intended.

Comment: Ok then, thanks for the tip!